# How does re.match and re.search with '^' differ?

Tags: python, regex

It seems re.match and re.search w/ '^' are the same thing, except re.search
can use the re.MULTILINE flag making it even more flexible.

```
string ="""U.S. stock-index futures pointed
to a solidly higher open on Monday
North Korea. That issue overshadowed the state of 
the equity market, where earnings 
have been strong at a time of high 
employment and low inflation, 
as well as valuations that a
ppear elevated by many metrics, north korea"""

import re


re.search('^North Korea\.?', string)  # no match
re.match('^North Korea\.?', string) # no match
re.search('^North Korea\.?', string, flags = re.MULTILINE ).group() #match
```

Are there any benefits of using one over the other?

Comment: Why do you think they *do*, or *should*, differ?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation] that they are very different, as `match` only looks at the beginning of the string, while `search` looks through the whole string

Comment: @Professor_Joykill  I'm talking about using re.search with the `^` sign.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not sure what you are getting. Why do we need match if we can use search with the `^` that does the same exact thing?

Comment: `re.search('^North Korea\.?', string)`  and `re.match('^North Korea\.?', string)` should match. Please double check

Comment: @Moondra, if you're asking *why* there are two separate functions rather than one -- thus, asking for the reasoning behind the library design --
questioning language design decisions tends to lead to unconstructive questions with speculative and opinion-based answers, since unless the calls were added separately from each other (which, in this case, they weren't), there won't be a publicly accessible ticket, PEP or mailing list discussion describing rationale. Thus, only the author is able to provide an authoritative answer, and crowdsourcing bunch of 3rd-party guesses isn't helpful.

Comment: @HahaTTPro   Sorry, I left out a portion of the original string.  Going to fix it, but my question is still the same.

Comment: @HahaTTpro  I fixed it.

Comment: @Charles Duffy I'm not discussing rationale of the author.  Anyone who has solid knowledge of Regular Expressions would understand what the difference is.
There might be cases where one works and one doesn't. I don't understand why you think only an author would understand how two different methods works.

Comment: The equivalent to using `match` vs `search` is to have the `\A` regex which asserts at the start of the string. With `^` that can be the start of each line with the `m` flag for multiline.

Answer (score 0):

`re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning

```
>>> re.match("c", "abcdef")    # No match
>>> re.search("c", "abcdef")   # Match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at ...>
```

re.search() checks for a match anywhere in the string. If you want to find substring, use `re.search()`

```
>>> re.match("c", "abcdef")    # No match
>>> re.search("^c", "abcdef")  # No match
>>> re.search("^a", "abcdef")  # Match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at ...>
```

**Both case, search and match do the same thing because `^`**

^ (Caret.) Matches the start of the string. Thus, it force re.search to search from beginning of the string (without MULTILINE).

**With `^` and MULTILINE, `re.search()` and `re.match()` are different because:**

`re.match()` only find from the beginning of the string. So, if first line is not match, then it is not match.

`re.search()` match anywhere on the string, thus, it can match the second, third, ... new line.

In [document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match), it said

> Note however that in MULTILINE mode match() only matches at the
>   beginning of the string, whereas using search() with a regular
>   expression beginning with '^' will match at the beginning of each
>   line.

Comment: TL;DR: using ^ with `search` matches the beginning of each line, but only the first line in `match`

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the difference between the two when using caret with MULTILINE, but I'm wondering if there is a difference between the two when NOT using the MULTILINE flag. From my testing I couldn't find any, but maybe experienced users would know.